# PayPal donation button with price options dropdown sending empty/zero value

Tags: paypal

I am trying to generate a PayPal donation button with a price drop down and a Yes-No drop down. Button is working fine but the amount/price is going empty. Below is the html generated from PayPal's website. Could anyone please help? Thanks!

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="my@email.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="GB">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="IICC">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="GT7">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://website.org/">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://website.org/">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Select a donation category">Select a donation category</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
<option value="Red">Red £50.00 GBP</option>
<option value="Bronze">Bronze £100.00 GBP</option>
<option value="Silver">Silver £200.00 GBP</option>
<option value="Gold">Gold £300.00 GBP</option>
<option value="Platinum">Platinum £500.00 GBP</option>
<option value="Diamond">Diamond £1,000.00 GBP</option>
</select> </td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Do you agree?">Do you agree?</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os1">
<option value="NO">NO</option>
<option value="YES">YES</option>
</select> </td></tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select0" value="Red">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount0" value="50.00">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select1" value="Bronze">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount1" value="100.00">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select2" value="Silver">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount2" value="200.00">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select3" value="Gold">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount3" value="300.00">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select4" value="Platinum">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount4" value="500.00">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select5" value="Diamond">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount5" value="1000.00">
<input type="hidden" name="option_index" value="0">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Comment: What values are you actually trying to send? This: value="Red" or this:Red £50.00 GBP?

Comment: i am trying to send 50 as amount

Comment: Then 50 needs to be your value, not the color. A select field works by adding a selected tag to the selection when chosen and the value is read from the selected options "value" attribute. What purpose are those hidden fields serving at the bottom? If you set the value on the option, then that is what will be read.

Comment: You are right about the value. The thing is i have to send the name "Red" along with the value "50".

Comment: Do they have to be sent as different queries, or can you send them together like this:

<option value="Bronze 100">Bronze £100.00 GBP</option>

Comment: i have tried. it does not work that way.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, option_index is not supported by donation buttons (cmd = _donations). You may try to use a BuyNow button (cmd = _xclick) instead, or change the amount field into a drop down menu, like

```html
<select name="amount">
 <option value="50">Red</option>
 <option value="100">Bronze</option>
 <option value="200">Silver</option>
 ...
</select>
```